# Azure Pipelines - Microsoft-hosted agent - windows latest vs windows-latest

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-releases

In Azure DevOps Release Pipeline for a Agent Job I can choose either `windows latest` or `windows-latest` as Agent Specification for Agent pool Azure Pipelines. I have not seen this anywhere else and the documentation does not mention it either. Given that documentation mentions `windows-latest` I will use that.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Is this a legacy name that will be removed or where does it come from? I have not noticed this before.

Comment: I have not noticed that either. I guess a GUI bug. `windows-latest` is what you need. Try to select the one with the space and let us know the results

Comment: @GeralexGR Seems like it, tested below and both seems to target `windows-latest` which is equivalent to `windows-2022`

Answer (score 2):

Tested two releases with the different agents, both seem to target `windows-latest` according to documentation.

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/win22/20220522.1/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/releases/tag/win22%2F20220522.1

windows latest:

[image]

windows-latest:

[image]